# Pass AWS CodeBuild IAM Role inside Docker container [unable to locate credentials]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

The role configured on CodeBuild project works fine with the runtime environment but doesn't work when we run a command from inside the container, it says "unable to locate credentials".
Let me know how can we use the role out of the box inside the container.

Comment: You can pass the credentials as environment variable and then consume them while running

Comment: I do not want to pass it as an environment variable. Ideally the container runtime must have that role attached similar to how it works in ECS as task role.

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of credential source "EcsContainer" to assume role seamlessly without having to export new credentials in your buildspec.yml.

> credential_source - The credential provider to use to get credentials for the initial assume-role call. This parameter cannot be provided alongside source_profile. Valid values are:
>
> - Environment to pull source credentials from environment variables.
> - Ec2InstanceMetadata to use the EC2 instance role as source credentials.
> - EcsContainer to use the ECS container credentials as the source credentials.
>
> From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html

**Steps:**

Step-0: Create a new Role 'arn:aws:iam::0000000000:role/RoleToBeAssumed' and attach required policies to provide the permission required for the commands you are running during the build.

Step-1: Add sts:assumeRole permissions to your CodeBuild Service Role. Here is a sample policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::0000000000:role/RoleToBeAssumed"
        }
    ]
}
```

Step-2: Configure your build container to use the credential metadata as source for assuming the role. Here is a buildspec example:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 8
    commands:
      - aws sts get-caller-identity
      - mkdir ~/.aws/ && touch ~/.aws/config
      - echo "[profile buildprofile]" > ~/.aws/config
      - echo "role_arn = arn:aws:iam::0000000000:role/RoleToBeAssumed" >> ~/.aws/config
      - echo "credential_source = EcsContainer" >> ~/.aws/config
      - aws sts get-caller-identity --profile buildprofile
```

Comment: Thank you , very clean and helpful

Comment: In addition, I had to configure the assume policy document of the RoleToBeAssumed to allow the CodeBuild role to assume it.

Answer (score 5):

> If you need to run a Docker container in a build environment and the container requires AWS credentials, you must pass through the credentials from the build environment to the container.

```
docker run -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION -e AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI your-image-tag aws s3 ls
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-versions

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to assume the role manually and export the auth tokens. Make sure you have ASSUME_ROLE_ARN available as environment variable -

```
commands:
  - TEMP_ROLE=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn $ASSUME_ROLE_ARN --role-session-name temp`
  - export TEMP_ROLE 
  - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
  - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
  - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')
  - docker push $ECR_IMAGE_URL:$IMAGE_TAG
```