# How to generate an AWS profile in `~/.aws/config` for use in a CodeBuild Project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codebuild, dbt

I'm working with a tool called `dbt` and the database authentication method for the tool utilizes IAM.  Unfortunately, IAM profiles do not exist when CodeBuild projects are built because it utilizes Instance Profiles instead.  Beacause of this I am unable to connect to my database.

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072181/pass-aws-codebuild-iam-role-inside-docker-container-unable-to-locate-credential), I tried running `aws sts get-caller-identity` in the project to see if I was able to get some of the values I need returned, but it returned

```
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (***) could not be found
```

Does anyone have idea on how to generate my own `~/.aws/config` within a CodeBuild project?

edit: the tool uses boto3 to generate temporary credentials here: https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/blob/9d00c000720d17c42a4fa08a26b75bd500cc857f/plugins/redshift/dbt/adapters/redshift/connections.py#L101-L123

but it does not seem to be able to generate those credentials within a CodeBuild project.

edit:

`buildspec.yml`

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    MODELS_REPO: dbt-dev
    PYTHON_VERSION: 3.8
  parameter-store:
    AWS_ENVIRONMENT: "/cloudformation/environment"
    AWS_PROFILE: "/cloudformation/environment"
    CODEARTIFACT_COMPANY: "/codeartifact/company"
    GITHUB_OWNER: "/github/owner"
    GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN: "/secret/github/token"
    GITHUB_USER: "/github/user"

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
        python: "${PYTHON_VERSION}"
    commands:
      - pip install -r projects/${PROJECT_NAME}/requirements.txt
      - ./projects/${PROJECT_NAME}/.aws/phases/install.sh
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - ./projects/${PROJECT_NAME}/.aws/phases/pre_build.sh
  build:
    commands:
      - ./projects/${PROJECT_NAME}/.aws/phases/build.sh
  post_build:
    commands:
      - ./projects/${PROJECT_NAME}/.aws/phases/post_build.sh

cache:
  paths:
    - /root/.cache/pip
    - /root/.cache/pip/**/*
    - ~/.cache/pip
    - ~/.cache/pip/**/*
```

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean that instance profile doesn't exist? You add permissions to your CB using CB role.

Comment: I understand that, but I believe I need some sort of hacky solution to generate a config at `~/.aws/config` so that I can use the `dbt` tool.  This tool requires the ability to generate database credentials with IAM.

Comment: You can run [aws configure set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/set.html) with the values of parameters you want to set.

Comment: Can you post your buildspec.yml please?

Comment: @hephalump posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following script should work for your use-case:

```
apt install jq -y
creds=$(aws sts get-session-token)

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $creds | jq '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $creds | jq '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $creds | jq '.Credentials.SessionToken')

aws configure --profile $AWS_PROFILE set region "us-east-1"
aws configure --profile $AWS_PROFILE set output "json"
aws configure --profile $AWS_PROFILE set aws_secret_access_key "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
aws configure --profile $AWS_PROFILE set aws_access_key_id "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
aws configure --profile $AWS_PROFILE set aws_session_token "$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"
```

You can change the region for your needs.