# Unable to upload to S3 using STS credentials

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-sts

#### Describe the bug

I'm trying to integrate STS assumeRole based authentication to upload my files to S3 buckets...

Code Snippet

```js
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'ap-south-1',
  maxRetries: 3,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
})

const roleToAssume = {
  RoleArn: process.env.ASSUME_ROLE_ARN,
  RoleSessionName: 'codebuild',
  DurationSeconds: 900,
}

const sts = new AWS.STS({
  apiVersion: '2011-06-15',
  region: 'ap-south-1',
  endpoint: 'sts.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
})
sts.assumeRole(roleToAssume, function (err, assumedRole) {
    if (err) {
      reject__(err)
      console.log('err>>>', err, err.stack)
    } else {
      console.log(
        ' ~ file: uploadTos3.js:30 ~ sts.assumeRole ~ data:',
        assumedRole
      )

      fileArray.map((file) => {
        // Configuring parameters for S3 Object
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({
         accessKeyId: assumedRole.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: assumedRole.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: assumedRole.Credentials.SessionToken,
    })
        const S3params = {
          Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
          Body: fs.createReadStream(file),
          Key: generateFileKey(file),
        }
        s3.upload(S3params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err)
          } else {
            console.log(`Assets uploaded to S3: `, data)
          }
        })
      })
      response__()
    }
  })
```

but everytime `sts.assumeRole` throwing this error

```
InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid
--
823 | at Request.extractError (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)
824 | at Request.callListeners (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
825 | at Request.emit (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
826 | at Request.emit (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
827 | at Request.transition (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
828 | at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
829 | at /var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
830 | at Request.<anonymous> (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
831 | at Request.<anonymous> (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
832 | at Request.callListeners (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
833 | code: 'InvalidClientTokenId',
834 | time: 2023-05-18T13:59:07.868Z,
835 | requestId: '3bc35552-7494-4605-9380-1fb8743e7d51',
836 | statusCode: 403,
837 | retryable: false,
838 | retryDelay: 62.92943618134528
839 | }
```

Scenerio-2
Here, Instead of using `sts` from `aws-sdk` I'm using aws-cli in docker image & passing `assumedRole.Credentials` from cli.

```
Command:
aws sts assume-role --role-arn $ASSUME_ROLE_ARN --role-session-name codebuild

-- Providing Credentials
```

But here also, I'm not able to use these credentials with aws-sdk
like this

```
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({
          accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
          secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
          sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
        })
        const S3params = {
          Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
          Body: fs.createReadStream(file),
          Key: generateFileKey(file),
        }
        s3.upload(S3params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            // Set the exit code while letting the process exit gracefully.
            console.error(err)
            process.exitCode = 1
          } else {
            console.log(`Assets uploaded to S3: `, data)
          }
        })
```

Here Getting this error

```
InvalidToken: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
--
16 | at Request.extractError (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:711:35)
17 | at Request.callListeners (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
18 | at Request.emit (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
19 | at Request.emit (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
20 | at Request.transition (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
21 | at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
22 | at /var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
23 | at Request.<anonymous> (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
24 | at Request.<anonymous> (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
25 | at Request.callListeners (/var/loco/loco/node_modules/.pnpm/aws-sdk@2.1379.0/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
26 | code: 'InvalidToken',
27 | region: null,
28 | time: 2023-05-18T13:44:22.058Z,
29 | requestId: 'CH90H7F00MZ4AYQB',
30 | extendedRequestId: 'SHL6HZeiY9Ts+Iu+RGahpQufpxTigrEmOO0t4ICtlqJ9AjEoREb6pRai4XtfDpxLqiN3VjmrQEM=',
31 | cfId: undefined,
32 | statusCode: 400,
33 | retryable: false,
34 | retryDelay: 0.14215548664469058
35 | }
```

#### Expected Behavior

I want to setup STS assumeRole & use those credentials to upload file to S3.

There might be the RoleARN access issue, But I'm unable to identify that as well

#### Current Behavior

1. Abel to setup STS assumeRole credentials using aws-cli but unable to use with S3 from aws-sdk
2. Not able to setup STS assumeRole using aws-sdk

#### Reproduction Steps

Same as above

I'm writing the code in upload_to_bucket.js file & running the same using Docker `node upload_to_bucket.js`

#### Possible Solution

idk, but it would be great help if anyone answer this.

#### Additional Information/Context

Ping me / Mail me @sanskardahiya98@gmail.com for any further information.

#### SDK version used

"aws-sdk": "^2.1379.0"

#### Environment details (OS name and version, etc.)

AWS Codebuild

Comment: Do you possibly have some credentials defined in an Environment Variable? If so, it might override the Security Token you are providing.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60086132/7363182 After that, remove the `assumeRole` code and also the credentials params from the `AWS.config.update`, because the SDK automatically get them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code is correct itself, Issue was due to restricted access, My EC2 machine does not have access to STS,

It is fixed by providing appropriate access.